# insertAfter is not working

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add some data after label element. It is working fine with after method, but if i tried the same using inserttAfter method, it is not working. Following is my snippet, can any one tell me, why insertAfter is not working.

```
<body>
    <label>Java</label>
    <br />
    <label>Python</label>
    <br />
    <label>Perl</label>
    <br />

    <script type="text/javascript">
        var jq = jQuery.noConflict();

        jq(" Programming").insertAfter("label");

        //jq("label").after(" Programing");
    </script>
</body>
```

Comment: you are selecting Programming with a space, no such html element present in html.

Comment: `insertAfter()` works perfectly fine. On the other hand, `jq("Programming")` attempts to match all the `<Programming>` elements in your document, of which there are none.

Comment: you can't use jq("Programming") to create a simple string - that constructor is for creating elements (or jQuery arrays of elements). Read the docs! http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/

Comment: Ya got it. By using following statement, i can able to resolve. jq("<label> Programming</label>").insertAfter("label");

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `jq('Programming')` search for tag `Programming` since there is no such tag nothing will append. So use **[`insertAfter()`](http://api.jquery.com/insertafter/)** only when you need to insert a jQuery element, not for text.

---

For inserting `Programming` text after the label use **[`after()`](http://api.jquery.com/after/)** method instead.

```
jq("label").after(" Programming");
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label>Java</label>
<br />
<label>Python</label>
<br />
<label>Perl</label>
<br />

<script type="text/javascript">
  var jq = jQuery.noConflict();
  jq("label").after(" Programing");
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

For jq(" Programming"), it will search the HTML tag **Programming** , but as there is no such tag in your DOM with name  and it will return blank. Like this:

```
jq(" Programming") = []
```

So you will have to add a tag(or temporary tag to work with insertAfter). Like this:

```
jQuery("<p> Programming</p>").insertAfter("label");
jQuery("<temp> Programming</temp>").insertAfter("label");
```